# Send GPO to non-domain Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, group-policy

I need to have the same base Group Policy settings on multiple non-domain Windows 10 systems.  If the computer is joined to a domain, I would like those settings to form the base policy over which the Domain GPOs are placed.  I can create a GPO in Server 2016, but how do I get the non-domain system to use it?

Alternatively, is there a better way to do this?

For reference, this needs to be done to many computers, each of which will be delivered to a different customer.  The customer will have the ability to join it to their Domain if they wish.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been digging some more, and I believe I have found a solution.  It will require additional testing to verify that this will work for me, but it looks good so far.

LGPO.exe
V1.0
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/secguide/2016/01/21/lgpo-exe-local-group-policy-object-utility-v1-0/

V2.0 Prerelease
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/secguide/2016/09/23/lgpo-exe-v2-0-pre-release-support-for-mlgpo-and-reg_qword/

While these tools can't work from a Server GPO, they allow a local policy on a computer to be exported, then imported into another system.

These tools are the replacement for the unmaintained LocalGPO tool that ships (shipped?) with SCCM.